# How do you solve the Silver Hand quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a problem with the Silver Hand quest. I've become a werewolf and I've completely clear out the Silver Hand hideout and Skinner, the Chief Silver Hand, with my companion member Aela. I've returned to Whiterun and the quest is marked as solved in my diary, but when I ask for work my companions tell me I am already working on something.

I can't find a new quest in my diary and I don't have the battle-axe Wuuthrad. I've searched the hideout several times but I can't find the Wuuthrad. What work are they referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Retrieval quest involves finding the Fragment of Wuuthrad, however you do not find it in the same hideout where you slayed the Silver Hand chief.

See detailed info [here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim/Retrieval)